# How exactly does `if $cmd ; then $cmd ; fi` differ from `$cmd && $cmd`?

Tags: shell, shell-script, posix

In an answer to another *very good* question I made the following assertion:

According to my reading of the POSIX specs, the use of one or the other makes no difference from a parsing standpoint.

POSIX specifies that `&&||` lists are *compound commands* which means that the entire list must be read in and parsed before execution of the constituent simple commands. POSIX also specifies a command *shall not be expanded* if it follows an `||OR` and another command with a 0-exit status. When you consider that a command following an `&&||` reserved word can easily be another grouped `{ command || ( command ; list) ; }` makes each branch of the `&&||` or list its own *compound command*.

But POSIX also specifies that each branch of the `if...;then...;else...fi` construct be its own *compound command* in this way:

```
if compound-list
then
    compound-list
[elif compound-list
then
    compound-list] ...
[else
    compound-list]
fi
```

> The `if` *compound-list* shall be executed; if its `exit` status is zero, the `then` *compound-list* shall be executed and the command shall complete...

It is this specification that the string following a `then...` or `else...` reserved words are *compound commands* in their own right and not merely *simple commands* that means the shell's parser must denote them with a command and a delimiter in order to operate correctly.

So basically, `then ' '` doesn't work for the same reason:

```
function()
sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

...doesn't - it doesn't make any sense.

I know that...

```
[ -e doesntexist ] && $((i=1)) ; echo $i
```

...will short-circuit any side-effects and result in only a `\n`ewline as a result of the spec I noted in my answer. The result of...

```
if [ -e doesntexist ] 
    then $((i=1))
fi
echo $i
```

...is identical.

But I honestly use `if...fi` so seldom that I'm unsure if I've misread something and so when I received a comment indicating my interpretation was incorrect and that if I had further questions on the matter I need only ask I deleted the answer in lieu of this question: how have I got it wrong - how do they differ?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - No, I meant `[ -e doesntexist ] && $((i=1))` actually, but I'd already edited that, hadn't I? I'm specifically talking about the parse order - sometimes commands are evaluated more times than they are executed, which is why `: $((i=1)) ; echo $i` will get you `1`.

Comment: I remember a question (or comment discussion) about this equality. I said there that they were not equal in certain circumstances. That referred to lists with more than one `&&` or `||`. The difference is that if the `then` block is executed then the `else` block is never executed. But with `&& / ||` it always depends on the exit code of the currently executed block.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand what you mean. `: $((i=1)) ; echo $i` is a strange example as there is no control flow at all. `:` is executed (it's a noop, **not** a comment!), and `$((i=1))` is not a command at all but an expansion.

Comment: `[ -e doesntexist ] && $((i=1)) ; echo $i` doesn't output `1` – except for if `i` was `1` before already...

Comment: @HaukeLaging - I know - `:` is `:`null. It does nothing *gracefully*. Its commandline is evaluated but it is not executed. In any case, I dunno what shell you're using but `echo $i ; sh -c ': $((i=1)) ; echo $i'` gets me a `\n`ewline then `1`. That's what I mean by parse order and their effects. Still, the first thing you said sounds like it might be on the mark - can you expand on that?

Comment: Expand on what exactly?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - The difference you mentioned. It sounds right. I think it's the same thing I mean by `... || { command || ( command list ) ; }` but I'm not sure. Like I said - I don't know. Oh, but `[ false ] && $((i=1)) ; echo $i` being a newline is what I mean when I say that it is short-circuited - it is not even evaluated.

Comment: `if true; then { echo true; test -e doesntexist; }; else echo false; fi` vs. `true && { echo true; test -e doesntexist; } || echo false` vs. `true && { echo true; test -e /; } || echo false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only simple cases can be expressed with `&&` and `||`. The `if` construct is more general. `if CONDITION; then FOO; fi` is equivalent to `CONDITION && FOO` (assuming proper usage of braces to delimit a block if necessary), but as soon as there's an `else` (or `elif`), this is no longer possible in general.

```
if CONDITION; then FOO; else BAR; fi
```

is not equivalent to

```
CONDITION && FOO || BAR
```

If `CONDITION` is true, both constructs execute `FOO`. If `FOO` is false, then the `if` construct skips `BAR`, whereas the `&& … ||` construct executes `BAR`.

And no, you can't work around this with `CONDITION && { FOO; true; } || BAR`. This makes the compound command return true if `CONDITION` is true and `FOO` is false, whereas `if CONDITION; then FOO; else BAR; fi` returns false in that case.

That's for the semantic difference. In addition, there's readability: nested uses of `&&` and `||` very quickly become hard to decipher. I don't recommend using both in the same command, in fact — especially given that the two operators have equal precedence in the shell, whereas they have different precedences in C and most other C-inspired languages (including Perl and Ruby).

Comment: Thanks, Gilles. Dang. I knew there was a reason I didn't like accepting them too soon. But you can do `cmd && { cmd || cmd ; }` right? I mean, that approximates `if cmd then { if ! cmd... ; }` at least, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`if testlist; then  else ...fi` and `testlist && thenlist || elselist` are not equivalent in general. The difference is that in the `if` construct exactly one of `thenlist` and `elselist` is executed. In the other case it depends on the exit code of `thenlist` (and possible `eliflist` blocks).

Thus you have to add (e.g.) `true` at the end of a selected result list so that the list has the same exit code like the test list that caused its execution.

```
if true; then
  echo true
  test -e doesntexist
else
  echo false
fi
```

can be rewritten with `&&` and `||` by making sure the exit code of the code blocks. Instead of

```
true && { echo true; test -e doesntexist; } || echo false
```

you need

```
true && { echo true; test -e doesntexist; true; } || echo false
```

**elif**

```
if test -e exists; then
  echo true
elif test -e doesntexist
  echo elif
else
  echo false
fi
```

would be

```
test -e exists && { echo true; true; } ||
  { test -e doesntexist && { echo elif; true; } || echo false; }
```

Comment: Thanks, Hauke. The `elif` isn't exactly `elif`, though, right? It's `if...fi ; if [ $? = 0 ] ...`. Same goes for `else...` approximation as well, I guess, which is why I deleted my comment before - not only is there no `elif` there's not even any `else...`, really, only `if...`/`if !...`, I guess. It was your own comments that led me to understand that a little better, I think. So I upvoted your answer, but if you could talk about that angle a little I'd accept it. Unless I'm wrong again... Oh, and just `echo true` - `echo` always returns 0.

Comment: @mikeserv I guess it's an exact `elif`. `&&`/`||` is always `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` / `if [ $? -ne 0 ]` but that doesn't mean that the whole construct is not equivalent to `if elif else fi`

Comment: Agreed that the evaluation is equivalent, but the parsing is not, which is what I think I got wrong. Honestly, as I said before, I so seldom use `if...fi` that I didn't really know, and I thank you for teaching me, but the question is *how do they differ?* because someone said I was wrong when I said they were equivalent for basically the exact same reasons. So, I guess what I'm asking you to do is to specifically address the question if you would.

Comment: @mikeserv I have added the explanation from my question comment to the answer.

Comment: @mikeserv Whatever. As I recently learnt the hard way you can change the accepted answer later. That's probably easier as you are notified about new answers but AFAIR not reminded of accepting one. I would be a bit surprised to see other answers here anyway...